# Wordpress hook before edit.php loads

Tags: php, wordpress

this seems so trivial, yet I can't find solution.

I have custom filters for posts. And not every user can edit every post. It depends on a custom meta tag. ( This is not so important )

Improtant thing is if they use URL something like `

> /edit.php?post=467

They can get to the post that I "didn't allow them".

What I am looking for is, whether there is possibility to get an URL in hook like

> admin_init

So I could do something like

```
if (!isset($_GET['post'])){ //redirect }
```

or

```
if ($_GET['post'] == $forbidenID) { //redirect }
```

Thanks guys. :-)

Comment: You may have more help for that on the site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I might try if noone helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I just realized you're in edit.php, meaning the admin area of WordPress... In that case, as you mentioned the `admin_init' action https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init

Try something like:

** QUICK THING: you said you want to redirect if `isset($_GET['post'])` right.. in your example, you said `!isset($_GET['post'])` So got to verify which of those you meant.

```
function restrict_admin_with_redirect() {

    if (isset($_GET['post'])) {
        wp_redirect( site_url() ); 
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_admin_with_redirect', 1 );
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

OTHER INFO:

If the page being executed is not in the admin area, but in the front-end of WordPress, like a normal page or post:

There are a few hooks that can be used for this. Also you can make an edit to your theme's `header.php` file as an option.

Check out the `the_content` filter: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

You can add this to your `functions.php` file (preferably, you should be using a child theme so changes won't get overwritten if the main theme is updated.)

```
function my_the_content_filter($content) {

  if (isset($_GET['post'])){
     return 'You do not have access to this page.';
  }

  // otherwise returns the database content
  return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```

Or at the very beginning of your header.php file (before any html is outputted), add something like this:

```
  if (isset($_GET['post'])){
     wp_redirect( {url to redirect to} );
     exit();
  }
```

Comment: I have tried exactly this one, before posting, and wasn't able to reach the $_GET global variable, for some reason. I might give it another try and post there what have  I come up with