# Wordpress hook before the edit post form is loaded

Tags: wordpress, hook

i'm looking, without exit, for a wordpress hook which is fired before the edit post page is loaded to prepopulate a field with values that i will get from the URL.
Any clue about if this hook exists?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best hook for this would be *admin_init.*

In addition, it looks like there is a more detailed answer for this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103863/wordpress-hook-before-edit-php-loads).